# Streaming file data from NodeJS and saving/downloading it on client

Tags: node.js, fs

I have a NodeJS based server, which reads an encrypted file, decrypts it and then I have a large file (~1GB) in a variable. **Now I need to send this file to client and make client download it**.
My server side code currently looks like this :
[image: Server code]

Variable `plain` contains the decrypted file data in bytes form.

On client part, I have EJS based views.
Client side code looks like this :
[image: Client side JS script]

Other questions I have -

1. Can I directly stream the file from variable and assemble/save it on client?
2. Or I need to save it to a file and then send the file content.
3. I am using busboy for file upload. Can it help in this task in some way?

Answer (score 0):

you can use something called stream.PassThrough() to stream your decrypted buffer to client side..
Here is the attached example you can try...

```js
var stream = require("stream");
var readStream = new stream.PassThrough();
// create stream
readStream.end(plain);
// Send your response
readStream.pipe(res);
```

Let me know if this work

**Note:** "Plain" should be a **buffer** of data/file.

"**res**" is your response from api method
-- example >> app.get("/:name", async (req, **res**) => .. so on